# Change default Laravel "Server error" message

Tags: laravel

I've noticed that in production mode with my debug mode set to **false** that most of my functions that have a `try/catch` will return the Laravel default "Server error" message.

I've been trying to hunt this message down with little luck, how can I customise this generic message returned from functions within my Laravel app whilst debug is turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to a very generic `HTTP 500` error, it's a blade file in the framework.

If you want to display your own error for `5XX` errors and such, you can override them by creating a blade file with the name of the error you want to override. For example:

**resources/views/errors/500.blade.php**

```
{{ __('Uh oh. Something has gone wrong behind the scenes.');
```

Now when a `500` error is encountered, your `blade` error will be displayed rather than the default Laravel `500` error.

You can create files for the common errors too obviously.

**Update**

The default messages for `HTTPExceptions` in Laravel are provided by the Symfony `Response` class found in the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation` directory.

When it comes to providing error messages in `APIs`, most will send the default `HTTP status code` in the headers and then supply a human error message in the response body.

For your example you might do something like:

```
return response()->json([
    'errors' => [
        [
            'status' => 500,
            'title' => 'Internal server error',
            'message' => 'A more detailed error message to show the end user'
        ],
    ]
], 500);
```

You would then be responsible for consuming the error response and showing the end user the `human readable` error rather than the default generic `Internal server error`.

You might find some of the [JSON API examples](https://jsonapi.org/examples) useful.

Comment: This is a Laravel API I've built, there are no blade files

Comment: @RyanH That's a key bit of information you might want to include in your question. :)

Comment: @RyanH I have added how you might handle this in an `API` environment. A downvote feels harsh considering I was not to know you were working with an `API`. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Model extends Authenticable.

I changed it to Model and imported Eloquence.